# IIS7 Serving .mp4s, not playable on iOS devices

Tags: iis7, video

I've added the proper MIME type to the server, made sure it applies to not only the specific site but even the all of server's sites.

The file is accessible and playable in my browser (Chrome) but when trying to pull it up on an iPhone , the debug mode warns me that the "movie could not be played" but on iPad it's "byte_range_error_message"

I'm really at a loss here of why iOS devices won't load the video up. I know it's not the video files themselves because I had used the same file on a different server (on a shared hosting package).

Any help is appreciated!
-Dan

Comment: Have you looked at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240915/h-264-encoded-mp4-presented-in-html5-plays-on-safari-but-not-ios-devices ?

Comment: Also https://discussions.apple.com/message/12320329?messageID=12320329

Comment: Yeah, it's not the video encoding. Once I put them them on a different server, it loaded up just fine. It's definitely a configuration on my server.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you added the correct mime-type to the server?  When I test it here locally the iPad seems to be sensitive to which mime-type is used in the response. I've tested it with `video/mp4` which seems to work fine but `video/mpeg` doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the problems I've had serving mp4s (or any media for that matter) was that I had forgotten to whitelist those filetypes from the web server's compression.

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: Well in my case, at the time, I had taken the route of compressing everything then whitelisting the mime-types that I didn't want gzipped. I'm doing the opposite now (gzipping only the text files being served). I made these directives in Apache's httpd.conf using mod_deflate. I'm not sure how you would do this for IIS7 but Google will.

Comment: Ok, thanks - I'm already doing it like you (on apache) but it still doesn't work. This movie streaming on mobile devices is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 3):

What you should look into whether or not there is an issue with the "byte range" HTTP requests feature of IIS7.  Any issue with that would cause the byte_range_error_message error.

For example, here's an IIS 7.5 hotfix for byte range requests that was causing problems with streaming PDFs: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/807/cpsid_80780.html

Since IIS7 typically supports byte range requests by default, you might need to look at what else is configured on your server (firewalls, HTTP filters, caches, routers, etc.).  I recently experienced the same issue and wrote up an article here:

[QuickTime BYTE_RANGE_ERROR_MESSAGE Error MP4 video](http://www.somacon.com/p571.php)